# Smooth rotation for a bone?

Tags: unity, bones

I'm trying to make my character bone "chest" rotate smoothly when face enemy and get back to his stand. Can anyone help me with this ?

```
public Transform Target;
public Vector3 Offset;

Animator anim;
Transform chest;

public float rotation_speed;
public bool aim_at_traget = false;

void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    chest = anim.GetBoneTransform(HumanBodyBones.Chest);
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (aim_at_traget == true) {
    // smooth rotation to face target
    chest.LookAt(Target.transform.position);
    chest.rotation = chest.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(Offset);
    }
    else {
        // get back to you stand smoothly 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In LateUpdate(), I would change the code to be this:

```
if(aim_at_target == true) {
   Quaternion rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(Target.transform.position - transform.position);
   chest.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(chest.rotation, rot, Time.deltaTime * 
   YOUR_SMOOTHNESS_VALUE);
}
```

Not sure what 'Quaternion.Euler(Offset)' is exactly but you probably can just multiply it in the second parameter of Quaternion.Slerp().

I did not test this, so may have a small mistake, I'm just giving you an idea to proceed and make it a smooth rotation.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. you code give me error on first line. I tried to do what you said. Using Slerp but still I can't see smooth movement. What else you advice me to do ?

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion'

Comment: Perhaps try adding (Quaternion) before Chest.LookAt

Comment: I did this but nothing change. Thank you Vadim for all what you did for me.

Comment: Edited my answer, check if it works. Remove (Quaternion) that I told you to put in my previous comment

Comment: If i removed i get the same error.

Comment: Did you try the new code from edited question ^

Comment: Thank you Vadim. Now i notes the new script. I used it and I see character armies shaking like something blocking them. Maybe this because i'm using Mecanim IK. Can I contact you by email ? Because this topic will transfer to chat and I can't open one.

Comment: Sure, Let me know your email and I’ll send you a message